# Read user defaults of another app in Swift

Tags: swift

In Swift 3+ on macOS 
I have an app running under the bundle identifier `com.bla.bla`:

I can read a key with

```
UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "mykey")
```

I can also erase key from other bundle with:

```
UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: "com.foo.bar")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

But how can I read a key from another app under the bundle identifer `com.foo.bar` ?

In command line it is:

```
defaults read com.foo.bar anotherkey
```

How can I do the same in Swift?

Comment: Have you tried `UserDefaults(suiteName: "com.foo.bar")?.string(forKey: "mykey")`? This could work with macOS. With iOS it couldn't.

Comment: Do you own the other app?

Comment: yep I own both, but I don't see why it matters.

Comment: Are you using iOS or macOS?

Comment: @macmoonshine you're right it works with what you suggested.

Comment: I've posted my comment as answer. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create user defaults for any app in macOS with its bundle identifier:

```
if let theDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "com.foo.bar") {
    let theValue = theDefaults.string(forKey: "mykey")

    ...
}
```

With iOS this works only for shared group containers.

Comment: I might be wrong, but this doesn't work with sandboxed apps